# How to implement ObjectListView delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to use `ObjectListView`, and set a delegate to influence the `AspectToStringConverter` process. the code is very simple

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.objectListView1.SetObjects(Song.GetSongs());
    this.titleColumn.AspectToStringConverter = delegate(object x)
    {
        return "aaa";
    };
}
```

It should be that the `titleColumn` text will all be replaced by `"aaa"` but this does not happen. Also, when trying to debug. I placed a breakpoint in

```
return "aaa";
```

and found that the program never reaches this point.

What can be the reason for that ?

Comment: Are you calling the delegate? Or merely declaring the delegate?

Comment: I am not calling the delegate, because ObjectListView is supposed to do the calling.

Comment: I fell that my problem is that none of the delegates that is supposed to be called by it, is not called, and I don't know why !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hours, and with pure luck, I found the answer to my own question....

Apperantly, you need to place the SetObjects call AFTER the delegate assignment!

Comment: Thanks. Wasted half a day trying to figure this out.